# Problems with parse while encoding ascii string

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to encode a string `VULGO PIVETÃO`, but i'm getting an error `URI must be ascii only "https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/playerscores?summonerName=VULGO PIVET\\u00C3O" (URI::InvalidURIError)`. I have tried the following block:

```
URI = "https://127.0.0.1:2999"

ENDPOINTS = { 
    allgamedata: "liveclientdata/allgamedata",
    activeplayer: "liveclientdata/activeplayer",
    playerlist: "liveclientdata/playerlist",
    eventdata: "liveclientdata/eventdata",
    playerscore: "liveclientdata/playerscores"
} 

def get_playerscore summoner_name
    summoner_name = "VULGO PIVETÃO"

    begin
        encoded_string = URI.parse(summoner_name)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
        encoded_string = URI.parse(URI.escape(summoner_name))
    end

    JSON.parse(Utils.req("GET","#{URI}/#{ENDPOINTS[:playerscore]}?summonerName=#{encoded_string}", {}, false))
end
```

But i'm still getting another error: `rescue in get_playerscore': "https://127.0.0.1:2999" is not a class/module (TypeError)`

> SOLVED

According to `@mu is too short` suggestion, using the library: *Addressable*, I solved the problem with this block of code:

```
uri = "#{URI}/#{ENDPOINTS[:playerscore]}?summonerName=#{summoner_name}"
uri = Addressable::URI.parse(uri)
uri = uri.normalize

JSON.parse(Utils.req("GET", uri, {}, false))
```

Comment: I tend to use [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) instead of `URI` from the standard library, more friendly to modern character sets.

Comment: `summoner_name = URI.escape("VULGO PIVETÃO")` should have been enough, as you don't care about human readable URLs when querying an API